# Databinding the contents of a list to a datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio, entity-framework

I recently made a list consisting out of rows in a pre-existing table and wanted to try and databind that list to a datagrid. It however shows nothing but the already defined column names. Does anyone know why this binding won't work?

```
    public class ViewModel1 : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    public List<Table1> AllDatainTable { get; set; }

    private void SetInitialSettings()
    {
        AllDatainTable = new List<Table1>();
    }
    public List<Table1> GetAllDatainTable()
    {
        List<Table1> ret = new List<Table1>();
        Table entity;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Testdatabase.dbo.Table1", "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=true");         
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            entity = new Testdatarow();
            entity.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
            entity.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            ret.Add(entity);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

And the xaml

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="6" x:Name="ContDatagrid" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AllDatainTable, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
             <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
             </DataGrid.Columns> 
        </DataGrid>
```

And the datamodel itself

```
public class Table1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int _ID;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set
        {
            _ID = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

And lastly the connection string which it does pick up on in some earlier tests

```
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConnectionToDb" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Testdatabase;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Do you ever actually call `GetAllDatainTable()` ?

Comment: Need extra ROWS or COLUMNS?
If columns, then replace `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`.

Comment: Have you set the data context of your window? You can do this for example in the xaml: `<Window.DataContext><local:ViewModel/></Window.DataContext>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrectly declared the type of the property-collection.
There must be an observable collection (with an INotifyCollectionChanged implementation) or a BindingList.

```
public class ViewModel1 : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ObservableCollection<Table1> AllDatainTable { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Table1>();

    public ViewModel1() => Update();

    public void Update()
    {
        AllDatainTable.Clear();
        foreach (var item in GetAllDatainTable)
            AllDatainTable.Add(item);
    }
    public IReadOnlyList<Table1> GetAllDatainTable()
    {
        List<Table1> ret = new List<Table1>();
        Table entity;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Testdatabase.dbo.Table1", "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=true");
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            entity = new Testdatarow();
            entity.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
            entity.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            ret.Add(entity);
        }
        return ret.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

And it is not clear from your code how you set this ViewModel to the DataContext of the Window, and how you call the data update method.
Therefore, it is likely that the error may not only be in the code you are showing.

Comment: It doesn't have to be observable or a binding list to just show the data as read only.

Comment: @Crowcoder, if the list is initialized in the VM constructor (that is BEFORE the binding is created), then you are right.
But judging by the TC code, it changes the collection after the binding is created.
In this case, you need to either completely replace the collection instance in the property with raising PropertyChanged.
Or it must be an observable collection.
Mutable or not the elements of the collection it is irrelevant.

Comment: I see, I'm relatively new to WPF, so the concept of a viewmodel that executes methods that another model would need to know is still quite foreign to me. What would be the best way to call upon this method in my .cs file? In an ideal scenario I would want the datagrid to be filled up when the application opens. The datacontext is set, if I bind to a completely empty list in my .cs Visual studio lets me know that it doesnt return a value, so the models are communicating

Comment: Add a default constructor to your ViewModel code: `public ViewModel1() => Update();`.

Comment: Aahhh I got it to work, thank you SO much!

Comment: I have made the appropriate changes to the response code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        ContDatagrid.Items.Add(dr);
    }
```

Comment: WPF DataGrid has no Items property, and this would not follow MVVM pattern which it appears the OP is at least making an attempt at.

Comment: @Crowcoder, You are not right.
The DataGrid derives from ItemsControl and inherits the Items property.
But I agree with you that the proposed code is very bad.

Comment: You are right I am not right. Edit your question and I'll take away the dv